# Arduino EEPROMex library problem

Tags: arduino-mega, eeprom, eepromex

I am trying to write a float value to the EEPROM on an Arduino MEGA2560. According to some research I should use Arduino EEPROMex library. I added the library to Arduino, but I get the message "EEPROM was not declared in this scope". How can I solve this problem or have you got any suggestions to do this?

Comment: Show us code...

Comment: It sounds like you've used the word `EEPROM` somewhere in your code without a function after it. As the first comment asks: CODE PLZ.